# Do LXC containers have access to PCI components such as PCIe SSDs and GPUs?

Tags: lxc, container

Do LXC containers have access to PCI components such as PCIe SSDs and GPUs?

Would the drivers need to be installed on the host, guest or both?

Do they support exclusive usage by using PCI passthrough like in a KVM?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, here is an example of it: http://www.jonnor.com/2010/03/hardware-passthrough-in-lxc-or-running-a-desktop-in-a-cgroup/.